# Having a limit to the amount of words shown according to <div> height

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Currently I have cards aligned horizontally that I want to be equal in height. The cards contain an image, a heading and a paragraph which is being fetched from my API. Reference Image:

[image]

The images and paragraphs for a few cards are bigger than the others which messes my alignment up. I want to be able to have a limit to the amount of words shown in a card according to height and not according to a word count, so that it can be fixed for every card and the last word should show a ... if the paragraph continues.

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-allen-4jsst?file=/src/App.tsx

Code:

```
<div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
              <div
                style={{
                  display: "block",
                  marginBottom: "20px",
                  cursor: "pointer",
                  textAlign: "center",
                  background: "#FEFEFE",
                  boxShadow: "0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
                  borderRadius: "10px"
                }}
              >
                <div>
                  <img src="blogContent.png" style={{ width: "100%" }} /> //Small Image
                </div>
                <div style={{ padding: "20px", textAlign: "start" }}>
                  <div style={{ color: "#0E2043", fontSize: "13px" }}>
                    Biometric Passport
                  </div>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      color: "#0E2043",
                      fontSize: "15px",
                      fontWeight: "600",
                      marginTop: "10px"
                    }}
                  >
                    Commonwealth Of Dominica Announces The Launch of its New
                    Biometric Passport
                  </div>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      color: "#0E2043",
                      fontSize: "13px",
                      marginTop: "10px"
                    }}
                  >
                    {" "}
                    //Small Content
                  </div>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      color: "#E3AB50",
                      fontSize: "13px",
                      marginTop: "10px"
                    }}
                  >
                    Read More
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
              <div
                style={{
                  display: "block",
                  marginBottom: "20px",
                  cursor: "pointer",
                  textAlign: "center",
                  background: "#FEFEFE",
                  boxShadow: "0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
                  borderRadius: "10px"
                }}
              >
                <div>
                  <img src="content2.png" style={{ width: "100%" }} /> //big Image
                </div>
                <div style={{ padding: "20px", textAlign: "start" }}>
                  <div style={{ color: "#0E2043", fontSize: "13px" }}>
                    Biometric Passport
                  </div>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      color: "#0E2043",
                      fontSize: "15px",
                      fontWeight: "600",
                      marginTop: "10px"
                    }}
                  >
                    Commonwealth Of Dominica Announces The Launch of its New
                    Biometric Passport
                  </div>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      color: "#0E2043",
                      fontSize: "13px",
                      marginTop: "10px"
                    }}
                  >
                    {" "}
                    // Big content
                  </div>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      color: "#E3AB50",
                      fontSize: "13px",
                      marginTop: "10px"
                    }}
                  >
                    Read More
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this div to textarea instead and then you can limit the words with maxlength=yourNumber attribute. Also, you'll have to hide the border so set in CSS border:none.

In order to set your images to the same size you should set the div wrapping it with a fixed size.

Something like this:

```
<div style={{width:'30px',height:'30px'}}>
<img src="blogContent.png" style={{ width: "100%"} }/>  
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Can you also have a look at why my images are not equal in height with each other and how I can make them equal